# Use SlidingPaneLayout to slide from bottom

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

Is there a way to get the SlidingPaneLayout to slide from bottom to top rather than from right to left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try out this library:

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

i think it matches your needs.

Comment: Yes this is what I ended up using.

Comment: @Rajul does this link works for u if used with viewpager